# How to log system command output in Rails under production mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm calling a C executable in my Rails(-v 2.3.5) application using the system() call.

```
makefile_path = File.expand_path('./c_executalbe', Rails.root)
system(makefile_path)
```

Everything works fine on my local machine but for some reason that system() call won't run on the server(dreamhost). And there is no error message in log/production.log. I would like to see the returned output of that system call in the log. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005960

Usage:

```
output = %x(command)
output = `command`
output = Kernel.send(:`, "command")
```

You'll get the command output.

If `command` comes from a variable, as in your case, you can interpolate:

```
output = %x(#{makefile_path})
output = `#{makefile_path}`
output = Kernel.send(:`, makefile_path)
```

To log it into `log/production.log`:

```
logger.info output
# or
puts output
```

Comment: I am unable to log it on production using Logger.info(cmd_output). I am using thin server.